# Write a SQL Cursor to duplicate existing rows and increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Apologies for the simplicity of this post, unfortunately, i'm not a SQL guru so this is beyond my meager skillset.

We have a table that contains schedule information for a webapp. Every month, we use the GUI to copy the next month's schedule across one day at a time. Instead of this process, I'd like to run a SQL script that does the same thing for me.

Take the results of the following query (seen below) which fetches about 340 rows

```
 select * from GSTProdSchedule where ShiftStartDate = 'd/m/yyyy 12:00:00 AM'
```

and insert a duplicate of every row for each day of the next month (modifying the three columns on the right).

Here's an example of the current data:

```
ID          GSTArea_ID  GSTShift_ID HourNumber  ShiftStartDate          HourStartTime           ShiftEndTime           
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- 
600543      2           1           1           2014-03-03 00:00:00.000 2014-03-03 04:30:00.000 2014-03-03 16:00:00.000
600544      2           1           2           2014-03-03 00:00:00.000 2014-03-03 05:30:00.000 2014-03-03 16:00:00.000
600545      2           1           3           2014-03-03 00:00:00.000 2014-03-03 06:30:00.000 2014-03-03 16:00:00.000
600546      2           1           4           2014-03-03 00:00:00.000 2014-03-03 07:30:00.000 2014-03-03 16:00:00.000
600547      2           1           5           2014-03-03 00:00:00.000 2014-03-03 08:30:00.000 2014-03-03 16:00:00.000
```

Thanks!

Comment: For what concrete database is this? *SQL* is just the query language - which is used by *many* database systems. Please update your tags to include the actual, concrete database you're using - whether that's MySQL, Postgres, IBM DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, Sybase, Interbase  - or whatever else you might be using - thanks!

Comment: Sorry - this is for MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

A way for doing that instead of using cursors, is by selecting the data in the specified range and by using the `DATEADD` function to add a month for each record of the result set which you want to be inserted as new records

Code sample for what you asks for (I haven't tested it)

```
INSERT INTO GSTProdSchedule
(GSTArea_ID, GSTShift_ID, HourNumber, ShiftStartDate, HourStartTime, ShiftEndTime)
select GSTArea_ID, GSTShift_ID, HourNumber,
DATEADD(m, 1, ShiftStartDate),
DATEADD(m, 1, HourStartTime),
DATEADD(m, 1, ShiftEndTime)
from GSTProdSchedule
where ShiftStartDate between '03/01/2014' and '04/01/2014'
```

I'm not a fan of cursor and I don't like to use unless I have to. Hope that works as you like

**Update:** I'm assuming that you are using MS SQL-Server.